# AngularCLI and Angular Material (schematics) error: Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli-v6

I am trying to use the Angular schemats that are shown on [this page.](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics)
When I try to use this following command in the terminal at the root of the project **ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name name-of-new-nav**, I get the following error in red,

> Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved. Error: Collection
>   "@angular/material" cannot be resolved.
>       at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (/Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:88:15)
>       at NodeModulesEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (/Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:106:27)
>       at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (/Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:78:40)
>       at SchematicEngine.createCollection (/Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:71:43)
>       at Object.getCollection (/Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/schematics.js:28:31)
>       at GenerateCommand.getOptions (/Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:193:41)
>       at GenerateCommand. (/Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:38:53)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at /Users/jeremypeters/MEGA/development/learning/angular/material-learn/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:7:71
>       at new Promise ()

How do I get this to work?

Info: Angular CLI: 6.0.8

Comment: Same problem here. If you google around, it's been broken for about 5 days now.

Comment: That's because `6.3.0` has a broken schematic file with a missing quotation mark. Here's a PR which fixes this: https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11839

Comment: Same problem. Use the accepted solution works for me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems broken, 
Temp solution, use the following version

```
ng add @angular/material@6.2.1
```

Comment: Thanks you, you saved my day too :)

Do you know if someone opened a bug for that?

Answer (score 8):

You can install it using:
`ng generate @angular/material:dashboard --name myDashboard`

For other components it will be:
`ng generate @angular/material:nav --name myNav`
`ng generate @angular/material:table --name myTable`

Info about other component schematics you can find in file, located in:
`/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/collection.json`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following cmds, It worked for me :

```
npm install --save @angular/material@6.2.1 @angular/cdk@6.2.1

ng add @angular/material@6.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me this way ([from docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics))

```
ng add @angular/material

ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name <component-name>

ng generate @angular/material:material-dashboard --name <component-name>

ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name <component-name>
```

Angular 6.4.7

Answer (score 0):

The Error is due to Angular Material 7. just run the following command in your terminal
ng add @angular/material@6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I found you're syntax wrong : `ng generate @angular/material:nav <name-of-new-nav>`.