# When trying to create navside bar getting a schematic error in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-schematics

Below error is thrown while trying to run `ng generate @angular/material-nav --name=main-nav` command in angular 6. Can anyone please help me to sort out this>

> Error: Schematic "@angular/material-nav" not found in collection
>   "@schematics/angular".

```
Dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

Comment: see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003953/angularcli-and-angular-material-schematics-error-collection-angular-materia

Comment: Tried the solution provided in here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003953/angularcli-and-angular-material-schematics-error-collection-angular-materia] , I'm able to add button component but unable to run 'ng generate @angular/material-nav --name=main-nav'

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any open issue on *GitHub* for the time being downgrade your `@angular/cdk:"6.0.0"` and  `"@angular/material": "6.0.0"`

Modify your package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/material": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
      },
```

Execute `npm i`